# overlapping elements in IE 8 only

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I've got a fiddle with the data here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ktpmm5/Z5z8n/

and page is staged here:

http://steppingstonez.com/daretorepair/magazines.php

Basically my paging element gets shoved to the left and lays over top of my heading.  This happens only in IE 8 - works fine in Chrome, FF and Opera.  I'm going crazy trying to figure out what is wrong.  html validates fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI re IE8: I see the overlap in IE7 compat & IE8 compat appears to be okay.  Are you seeing this in IE8 + compat mode?

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

To make it roughly work, change the paging wrapper to have the `position: relative`, and float the ul.paging right (remove the position).

You'll need to add height into the `head_text` to include the paging wrapper (as `paging_wrapper` is now positioned out of the flow, so its height does not count).

Longer solution:

Even with the fix above, you still have the problem that a long title will overlap regardless, so I would define the area/width of the header (making it wrap if too long) and also restrict the area of the paging device (by limiting number of buttons that show).

Answer (score 0):

Another quick solution: Specify the correct width for your `.paging` CSS class (UL). For example a width of `220px` seems correct.

```
.paging {
  ...
  ...
  width: 220px; /* new */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it seems more of an issue with utilizing negative margins.  You have both a margin-top on the paging_wrapper and the paging li a.  This is probably causing some weirdness for support in IE.